# How to drill a groove to the side of a plywood board?

Tags: woodworking, drill

I want to drive a cable up a cupboard. The shelves are too long to simply put the cable behind them, so I want to create an indentation in the removable shelves.
[image]

I do not own a drill press, and I do not want to buy one just for this. I do not even have the space for it. How can I do this with only a manual drill? Is [milling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milling_%28machining%29) a good idea, or should I press the shelf between two parts of wood, and just drill it?

As this is on the non-visible side of the shelf, a V shaped cut with a saw is also an option.

Comment: It's difficult to figure out what you're asking.  Do you want to drill an actual hole or route a dado/groove?  Because you mentioned drill press, this assumes you want to drill a very straight hole.  In that case, check out this: http://www.amazon.com/Gator-V-DrillGuide-Standard-Portable-Drilling/dp/B0061FY004.  I have one and they're a must-have for straight, accurate drilling if you don't own a drill press.  I drilled a 3/8" wide, 4" deep hole right into the edge of a 1/2" sheet of plywood once and the bit went straight in without coming out either side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just clamp a scrap of plywood to the top of the board and use a hole saw to cut through both boards.

Answer (score 1):

For a relatively small groove, a little bit of hand work with a round ("rat tail") file does wonders.

Answer (score 1):

If you're taking the shelves out to do this process why not just cut the corner off? It would look better than a hole. If you want to groove in a notch or dado then the rat tail file is a better option.